# mysqli fetch array error Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to **input and display the data on same page** through mysqli **but it shows an error "*Couldn't fetch mysqli on line*" and not unable to display the records**.

```
<?php

$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","abc")  or die("Not connected".mysqli_error());
$database=mysqli_select_db($db,'abc')  or die("Database not found".mysqli_error());

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $roll=$_POST['roll'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
$ins=mysqli_query($db,"insert into abc1 (roll,name)values('$roll','$name')");
}
mysqli_close($db);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
Roll No <input type="text" name="roll" />
Name <input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<table><tr>
<td>Roll No.</td>
<td>Name</td>
</tr>
<?php $query=mysqli_query($db,"select * from abc1");
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
$id=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>

<tr><td><?php echo $row['roll']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: side note: you should definitely sanitise your database input. in the current state, it is very vulnerable to SQL-injections http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Both of the answers are correct. Just one more thing, in the procedural way `mysqli_error()` function expects parameter 1 to be your connection handler. Please read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-description). And you're already connected to a database using `mysqli_connect()` so there's point using `mysqli_select_db()` again.

Comment: move  mysqli_close($db); at bottom of the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing mysqli_query twice. 
Try this.

`$query = "select * from abc1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);`

Comment: I tried this also but still showing error **Couldn't fetch mysqli on line on line $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);**

Comment: May be because you are closing the mysql connection on the top. Try removing that and check please.

Comment: Thanks @induprakash The error was due to closing the mysql connection on the top. Thanks again. Now it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling mysqli_query function twice:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"select * from abc1");
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

> Error: Couldn't fetch mysqli on line

Means, you are passing a a resource id in mysqli_fetch_array function instead of Query Statement. so you just need to use this as:

```
$query = "select * from abc1";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

**Side Note:**

There is no need to connect db again:

```
$database=mysqli_select_db($db,'abc')
```

`mysqli_connect()` already connected your db.

Comment: I also tried **$query="select * from abc1";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);** but same error

Comment: I tried this also but still showing error **Couldn't fetch mysqli on line on line $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);**

Comment: no need to connect db again.. and use mysqli_close($db); at bottom @Ronit